# MySQL: Avoid selecting columns with the same userid

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to select all columns but avoid more than 1 same userid.

```
$result = mysql_query("select *, DISTINCT userid from ringtones where deletedbyuser='0' and (lang='$lang' or lang='en') order by id desc limit 10");
```

Please help.

Table structure:

```
id  int(10)
userid  int(10)
artist  varchar(100)
title   varchar(100)
lang    varchar(2)
public  int(1)
status  int(1)
deletedbyuser   int(1)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the whole select. You cannot distinctly select one column.

Comment: Can you explain your table structure and what it is you are tring to achieve

Comment: What you probably want is some sort of grouping of your result set by userid. More info about your table structure and your goals is needed though.

Comment: Which `artist` to select if some `userid` have several different?

Comment: @Radio: just curious how **random** data is useful for your application?

Comment: @zerkms: nobody said random. like you said some userid have several ringtones, i want to display just one of them, does not matter which.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
select r.* from ringtones r 
    inner join (select MIN(id) as id, userid from ringtones 
                      where deletedbyuser='0' and (lang='$lang' or lang='en') 
                      group by userid) s
    on r.id = s.id
order by r.id desc
limit 10
```

this will pick the first one added if there are more than one.

Comment: on problem. hope you enjoy joining on sub-selects for similar issues in the future :)