# Joining in another table with possible new values for field

Tags: php, mysql

The query below works great.  It pulls ZIP codes from a table "submission," groups them, then lists them in order.

I have another table called "addresses" that has ZIP codes as well, which may or may not be duplicates of the ZIP codes in "submission."

How could I join any ZIP codes appearing in "addresses" (the second table), but not appearing in the first table, and add them to the list created by the query below?

```
$query2 = "SELECT submissionid, zip
FROM submission
GROUP BY zip
ORDER BY zip ASC";
```

Comment: have you tried the WHERE clause?
you will have to do an UPDATE to the table

Comment: Your `SELECT` is flawed. It does not make sense to select `submissionid, zip` and then group by `zip`. If you have many records with the same `zip` value, what value do you think mySQL will use for `submissionid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the union word and you can't use the submissionid

```
select zip from submission
union
select zip from addresses
```

union will give you distinct values by default. If you need the id, you can do something like this over the resulting query to select a specific one:

[MySQL: Avoid selecting columns with the same userid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792703/mysql-avoid-selecting-columns-with-the-same-userid)

This one uses the lowest id of a set of identical zips.

Answer (score 0):

you could also fake an id from the other table, since it does not have a submissionid with

```
select * from (
    select submissionid, zip from submission
    union
    select -1, zip from addresses
    )
order by zip asc
```

All the zip codes from the addresses table would have -1 instead of an id.